# API to read and write http headers?

Tags: joomla-api, header

I am wondering what is the best way to read and write http headers in Joomla?

What do I need to achieve?

- I want to read all requests headers
- I want to add response headers
- I want to control optional existing headers by removing them or modifying them
- I want to ensure my code is the last part of a possible chain of handling the http headers, so nothing else may modify my headers

Is where any good documentation how Joomla handles http-header processing? Is there something around like a chained processing (similar to c# or java http handling)?

What would you suggest to solve my above mentioned bullet-requirements?

Comment: This is several (related) questions in one.  Are you worried that your current programming is lacking? Can we see what you are using currently? If you have performed research and found some useful references, please include them so that we don't direct you to something that you have already read.

Comment: How far did you get with your development after reading this: https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Http.Http.html ?  Do you have an example situation to give your question context?

Comment: @mickmackusa thank you for the class reference. This is good to know there is a standard API
the second question block is around how to create a plugin which intercepts all requests to change the http headers. Do you have a suggestion for this? Maybe also a book for developing in joomla?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have anything more for you at the moment.  I feel my role here (since I seldom "have the answers") is to help people to sharpen their questions so that the experienced and knowledgeable volunteers can swoop in and post great answers to clear and narrow questions.

Comment: @laendle for a good book on programming plugin for Joomla see if you can find a copy of Programming Joomla Plugins by Jisse Reitsma. I got a copy second hand off Amazon a little while back but I have since come across a .pdf of the book somewhere on the internet but can't remember where I saw it. Jisse is no longer doing Joomla work and links to the book on his site are now broken. Tim Plummer has another good book for starting with Joomla development that I use as a reference also. Both are for Joomla 3.x but worth the money in my view.

Comment: Nutshell. Unless you control the configuration of your webserver completely, you can never ensure the headers don't get rewritten by the webserver on the way out. It handles the data *after* your code does. Always. (And for that matter, you can't stop any "middleman" such as a caching proxy from changing them.